# Sort RealmResults strings numerically?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-java

I need to sort this list of `String` which are actually large numbers (had to use that since `BigInteger` is not supported with Realm)

`RealmResults<Leaderboard> leaderboardList = realm.where(Leaderboard.class).distinct("score").findAll().sort("score",Sort.DESCENDING);`

The results are 5 `Strings` with the following numbers:
75,000
74,990
6,079,990
5,006,079,990
1,079,990

which display in that order when sorted by `Sort.DESCENDING`

I need to actually sort them correctly, and cannot get any solution with `Collection` working with the `RealmResults` list. Also having trouble using the `toArray()` method of `RealmResults` since in all cases there is some problem with differing types that I do not understand.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Try Collator if it's available http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=207

Answer (score 1):

`RealmResults` implements `java.util.Collection` so can't you just write

```
Comparator<Leaderboard> descendingScore = (l1, l2) ->
       (new BigDecimal(l2.getScore()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(l1.getScore()));
List<Leaderboard> leaderboardList = realm.where(Leaderboard.class)
    .distinctValues("score")
    .findAll()
    .stream()
    .sorted(descendingScore)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `stream()` , `sorted()` ,`collect()` and `Collectors.toList()` all require api 24 (min is 16) unfortuntely

Comment: @zngb Ah, sorry.  You didn't specify...  I suppose you could just copy them into a list manually and sort them?

Comment: I tried that and got those incompatibility issues.. do you have an example of what I could try? Thank you

Comment: Use static method `Collections.sort();` to apply the comparator if you cannot use streams